# How can I convert this type of date (22-07-2020 12:00) to ISO date

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to convert this type of Date

> 22-07-2020 12:00

to

> 2020-07-07T11:39:02.287Z

how can i do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function to convert a string `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`
date time to iso date

```js
function toIsoDate(dateTime){
    const date = dateTime.split(" ")[0].split("-");
    const time = dateTime.split(" ")[1].split(":");
    return new Date(date[2], date[1]-1, date[0], time[0], time[1]);
    // or if you want to return ISO format on string
    return new Date(date[2], date[1]-1, date[0], time[0], time[1]).toISOString();
}
```

`Date` accept these parameters: `(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`, keep in mind that the month value is 0-11, not 1-12, that's why we subtract the month (`date[1]`) on the function.

```js
const dateTime = "22-07-2020 12:00";
console.log(toIsoDate(dateTime));
```

> 2020-07-22T12:00:00.000Z